# Expressの全てのRoutingにおいて先に文字を表示したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

### やりたいこと

全てのエンドポイントであらかじめ`<body>`を表示しておきたい
全てのエンドポイントで`res.send(<body>..)`を先に書いておけば済む話なのですが、どこかでまとめられるならまとめたい

### 試したこと

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, console.log("サーバーが開始されました。"));

// ミドルウェアを使用するような形で実装してみましたがhoge関数内のres.sendが実行された時点で処理が止まる
// "/"にアクセスしてもffffgは表示されない
app.use(hoge);
function hoge(req, res, next) {
  res.send("<body>");
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("ffffg");
});
```

### なぜこの実装をしたいのか

`browser-sync`でクライアントサイドのホットリロードを実装したいのですが、
`body`要素をレンダリングしないと動かないのが理由です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response の `send` メソッドに細工をしておく方法です。

```js
app.use(hoge)
function hoge(_req, res, next) {
    res.origSend = res.send
    res.send = function (body) {
        this.origSend("追加文字列\n" + body)
    }

    next()
}
```

他に `write` などのメソッドを使っているならば、それらにも細工が必要になります。あまり綺麗な方法ではないでしょう。

---

開発中のみの処置とはいえ、HTML の先頭に `<body>` を追加すると、HTMLの構造を大きく損ない、テストが失敗するなどの問題が生じかねません。Browsersync の [snippetOptions](https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-snippetOptions) などで対処できるならば、その方がよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！